# How can I pass two separate structs to a function that accepts a single pointer?

Tags: c, pointers, struct

I have an function that has only one `(void*)` pointer for data transfer. But I need to transmit two different structures (`struct A` and `struct B`) at the same time using that `(void*)` pointer. Is it possible to store one structure after another by this pointer and then access data using structure sizes and offset?

Comment: Did you try to implement something by yourself ?

Comment: @GAURANGVYAS, yes I did. I tried to do some kind of serialization. But I didn't managed to do it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could do something like:

```
struct C 
{
    struct A myA;
    struct B myB;
};
```

Populate the `myA` and `myB` variables in `C`, and then pass a pointer to a `struct C` in your function.

Answer (score 2):

You can create a `struct` that holds two pointers, then pass the address of an instance of that `struct`:

```
typedef struct
{
    struct A *a_ptr;
    struct B *b_btr;
} struct_with_two_pointers;

...

struct A a;
struct B b;

...

struct_with_two_pointers X;
x.a_ptr = &a;
x.b_ptr = &b;

someVoidFunc( ( void * ) &X );
```

Answer (score 2):

> Adding  sample code snippet, if that helps.

```
typedef struct
{
    int age;
    int rollno;
}struct_A;

typedef struct
{
    char name[10];
     int marks; 
}struct_B;

typedef struct
{
    struct_A a;
    struct_B b;
}struct_C;

struct_C combined_struct = {{15,10}, {"Henry", 85}};  //Fill the structure here.

someRandonFunction((void*) &combined_struct); //Pass it.
```